# Fixed position button on iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing an iOS app with Xcode.

How can I create a button that holds a fixed position on the screen...even on a TableView?

One example is the blue round button that is at the bottom of the screen in some scenes on Foursquare app.

[image: Foursquare screenshot]

Comment: add button and use this `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];` to show sub view in front

Comment: I'm using a ListViewController, sorry for not saying it earlier. I tried to do it from storyboard...but the problem is that I couldn't find a way to put the button anywhere on the interface. Is there a programmatic way to do it?

Comment: add button programatically

Comment: yip that i can do, but the button scrolls together with the table content. is there a way to keep its position fixed somewhere on the screen even while the table cells are scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the button to the view that holds the tableView, not to the table view itself. Either bring it (the button) to front, or add it after the tableView so that it is in top of it.

Comment: hmm okay wait I'm on a ListViewController, sorry for not saying it earlier. I tried to do it from storyboard but I can't find a way to do it....should I create a standard ViewController and add the TableView only inside the view of that one? I don't know if then I have to change my code too... Otherwise, can I try to do it programmatically somehow?

Comment: You can use another ViewController and add a Table View inside it, yes. Then you can also add a button to the 1st ViewController's view which will stay on top and not move with the table view. And yes, you might need to change your code a little bit